# Undefined array elements in my automated javascript/chai tests

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, undefined, chai

I am using chai and javascript to run some automated tests against API endpoints.

In one of my tests, I am pushing results into an array (shown below, the array is named acceptanceCriteriaHashes).
If I put a breakpoint in the before code then I can see the array, and all the elements within the array, are fully populated with the object returned from the db call.

However when I actually come to verify the contents of the array later in the test, the array, although it has the correct number of elements, contains only undefined?

Have tried to push directly with the results of the db call and that doesn't work either?

```
const getAcceptanceCriteria = (testCase) => {
let getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse;
let myLicenceChecksPassed = false;

const acceptanceCriteriaHashes = new Array();

describeTest(`${testCase.testCaseId} - ${testCase.testDescription}`, async () => {
    before(async () => {
        if (testCase.myLicenceChecksPassed !== undefined) {
            myLicenceChecksPassed = testCase.myLicenceChecksPassed;
        }
        getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse = await getAcceptanceCriteriaAPICall(testCase.productId, testCase.assetType, testCase.underwriter, myLicenceChecksPassed);
        if (getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse != undefined && getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail.length; i++) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
                let response = await readAcceptanceCriteriaHashes(getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail[i].ContentHash);
                if (response != undefined) {
                    let record = { Hash: response.Hash, Criteria: response.Criteria };
                    acceptanceCriteriaHashes.push(record);
                }
            }
            console.log(acceptanceCriteriaHashes);
        }
    });
```

// other tests successfully run here

```
    it(`${testCase.testCaseId} - Record for contentHash exists in the AcceptanceCriteriaHashes table`, async () => {
        expect(acceptanceCriteriaHashes).to.not.be.empty;
        expect(getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail.length).to.eql(acceptanceCriteriaHashes.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < acceptanceCriteriaHashes.length; i++) {
            expect(acceptanceCriteriaHashes[i].to.not.be('undefined', `Returned undefined for ContentHash: ${getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail[i].ContentHash}`));
            expect(acceptanceCriteriaHashes[i].Criteria.to.not.be.empty);
        }
    });
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed to declare the record variable outside of the before code block otherwise, when we exited the before function, it ceased to exist by the time I came to query it in the subsequent test..
Declaration goes just before the before function:

```
const getAcceptanceCriteria = (testCase) => {
let getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse;
let myLicenceChecksPassed = false;
// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
// eslint-disable-next-line no-array-constructor
const acceptanceCriteriaHashes = new Array();
let record;

describeTest(`${testCase.testCaseId} - ${testCase.testDescription}`, async () => {
    before(async () => {
        if (testCase.myLicenceChecksPassed !== undefined) {
            myLicenceChecksPassed = testCase.myLicenceChecksPassed;
        }
        getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse = await getAcceptanceCriteriaAPICall(testCase.productId, testCase.assetType, testCase.underwriter, myLicenceChecksPassed);
        if (getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse != undefined && getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail.length; i++) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
                let response = await readAcceptanceCriteriaHashes(getAcceptanceCriteriaResponse.body.Detail[i].ContentHash);
                if (response != undefined) {
                    record = { Hash: response.Hash, Criteria: response.Criteria };
                    acceptanceCriteriaHashes.push(record);
                }
            }
            console.log(acceptanceCriteriaHashes);
        }
    });
```